# What's wrong with the sentence "I got so many requests to make some Valentine's Day treats.", if anything?

Tags: sentence-patterns

The word *so* feels wrong to me, but I can’t articulate why. I hear this pattern (*I got so many requests to **X**.*) frequently on a particular Youtube channel and I always think to myself *You got so many requests that what?*

Some definitions for *so* use it as above, but they tag it with the word ‘informal’, such as:

> 5. Informal. very or extremely: I’m so sad.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/so

That doesn’t tell me what's wrong with the sentence. Why is this use of *so* considered ‘informal’?

Comment: 'Why' is a difficult question to answer. It is much easier to confirm (or not) _that_ it is informal. It's not very informal: is more likely to be used in informal circumstances but it doesn't sound out of place in formal circumstances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you miss here is a *[final clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_clause),* of the sort that expresses not so much purpose as result. Such final clauses are commonly introduced by *that,* though the *that* is often optional. The following, for instance, would fulfill your expectation without *that:*

> I got so many requests to make Valentine’s treats, I had to spend my whole Sunday baking.

The expectation of a final clause after this sort of *so* is the mainspring of a standard sort of joke:

> My home town was so small . . . [chorused audience response “how small was it?”] . . . the general store only sold privates!

Using *so* as a simple intensifier, or in other words as a substitute for *very,* is a common colloquialism and need be eschewed only in formal register.

Comment: According to [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/so), intensifier 'so' isn't marked for register (unlike 'ever so'). << **So** adverb (VERY) A2 very, extremely, or to such a degree:
_The house is so beautiful_.>>

Comment: ... whereas RHK Webster's adds the usage note: The intensive so meaning “very or extremely” (Everything's so expensive these days) occurs chiefly in informal speech and **is occasionally criticized in other contexts**. In writing and formal speech, intensive so is most often followed by a completing that clause: Everything is so expensive that some families can barely afford necessities. [bolding mine]